# How to recycle random array values?

Tags: arrays, button, replace

I have a button that displays three random values from an array. I need a new button that replaces those three values with three new random values. Right now, I get nothing, or I get a button that keeps running the same thing, so if i hit the button twice, it would show the same 3 random values twice.

HTML

```
<button id = "test" onclick="myFunction();">Testing</button>
```

JS

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3]

function myFunction(){
  function secondFunction();
  for (i in arr) 
  { 
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    var answer = arr[random]; 
    document.write("<br / >" + answer);
  }
}

function secondFunction() {
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

Comment: But your array only has three elements, in order to show random values, you pool size should be big right.

Comment: This was just an example, but even if it has 5 elements lets say, it would still print the same 3 over and over, if that makes sense. So it would print 3 1 2, and then 3 1 2 again instead of lets say 2 1 1.

Comment: I just pushed all the random values to a new array and I get random values, you can also try it, push to an array and then iterate over that array and write to document.

Answer (score 0):

check out my implementation to get random values for an array.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3]

function myFunction(){
  var myRandomArr = [];  
  for (i in arr) 
  { 
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    var answer = arr[random]; 
    myRandomArr.push(answer);  
  }
  return myRandomArr;  
}

var arr1 = myFunction();
for (i in arr1) {
  document.write("<br / >" + arr1[i]);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Didnt seem to work for me:/ When i clicked the button, nothing happened

Comment: No you need to iterate over the myRandomArr

Comment: Sorry do u mind explaining that more; I have the code, and when I load the page it selects 3 random values, but my button still doesnt do anything.